# Getting an error when trying to create an agent pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to create a new agent but getting below error.

Any idea what is causing the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Microsoft [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=browser#authentication) describes as below. Please follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops-2019#confirm-the-user-has-permission) to check if you have the proper administrator permission to register an agent.

> To register an agent, you need to be a member of the [administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#security) in the agent pool. In addition, you must be a local administrator on the server in order to configure the agent.

You can also try using a Person Access Token with agent pools read&manage scope to [register your agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops-2019#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token-pat).

Answer (score 1):

this error means you dont have enough permissions to perform that action. you need agent pool administrator permissions to create pools